# multiple iteration through python dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a dictionary (mydict) in the following format

```
{'a':1, 'b':[{'example':'first','green':'second'},
{'apple':'third', 'green':'fourth'}]}
```

I'm trying to iterate over the dictionary and go 'b' and find all the keys that are 'green'.

```
results = {}
for key in mydict(b):
  results.append(b[y])
```

Comment: did you paste your `mydict` in correctly?

Comment: How does  'b'  fit into it? Your code is also syntactically wrong, do you  actually have a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that your input is:

```
D = {'a': 1, 
     'b': [ {'example': 'first', 'green': 'second'}, 
            {'apple': 'third', 'green': 'fourth'}]};
```

You can perform the task that you want with a simple list comprehension:

```
results = [item['green'] for item in D['b']]
# ['second', 'fourth']
```